# What does the 「な」 mean in 「出過ぎず、足りな過ぎずな完璧な躰は」?

Tags: grammar, meaning

The full sentence is below and the context is a guy, describing someone he just met.

> 出過ぎず、足りな過ぎず**な**完璧な躰は、淡い紫色の、俗に羽衣と呼ばれるゆったりとした服に包まれている。

I don't know what the 「な」 is doing/means.

Comment: 足りな過ぎず is treated as a な-adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already answered in the comment, "出過ぎず、足りなすぎず" as a whole is used as a na-adjective.

出過ぎず足りなすぎない完璧な躰 would be also fine and more "standard", but in this case 出過ぎず足りなすぎず is a kind of set phrase, so probably the author did not want to conjugate it.

Similar example:

> - 早い朝食 early breakfast
> - 早くな朝食 (incorrect)
> - 早くもなく遅くもない朝食 (standard)
> - 早くもなく遅くもなくな朝食 (perhaps nonstandard, but OK) not-so-early-but-not-so-late breakfast

Comment: so i'm guessing it would translate to something along the lines of "a flawless body, without being to forward while also not too lacking" while the actual meaning is something like it not being "not too much and not too little"?

Comment: Yes it refers to being not too ample nor slender.